# RSelenium error when connecting to server using Internet Explorer in windows

Tags: r, rselenium

I try to use the RSelenium in windows with IE as browser as it seems there are some discrepancies with other browsers, and need some fixing with the newer versions.
I do as previously instructed in SO answers:

```
library(RSelenium)
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver(browser="internet explorer")
remDr$open()

remDr$open()
[1] "Connecting to remote server"

Selenium message:Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{nativeEvents=true, browserName=internet explorer, javascriptEnabled=true, version=, platform=ANY}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
 Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
 System info: host: 'CL5065F329EBF2', ip: '130.115.158.36', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
 Driver info: driver.version: InternetExplorerDriver

 Error:      Summary: SessionNotCreatedException
 Detail: A new session could not be created.
 class: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException
 Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

Also when starting server or checking for servers I receive errors regarding deprecated use of the function.

For example:

```
startServer()

Warning message:
startServer is deprecated.
Users in future can find the function in   file.path(find.package("RSelenium"), "example/serverUtils").
The sourcing/starting of a Selenium Server is a users responsiblity. 
Options include manually starting a server see vignette("RSelenium-basics", package = "RSelenium")
 and running a docker container see vignette("RSelenium-docker", package = "RSelenium")
```

Comment: `startServer` and `checkForServer` are deprecated. The recommended way to run a Selenium server is via docker see http://rpubs.com/johndharrison/RSelenium-Docker

Comment: Thanks, I indeed switched to using that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Internet explorer to do some web scraping, you can consider using the RDCOMClient R package.

```
library(RDCOMClient)
IEApp <- COMCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE
IEApp$Navigate("https://www.google.com")
```

You can also use RSelenium with PhantomJS :

```
library(RSelenium)
library(wdman)

port <- as.integer(4444L + rpois(lambda = 1000, 1))
pJS <- wdman::phantomjs(port = port)
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs", port = port)
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://www.google.com")
```